# Set IP_HDRINCL with PF_PACKET error in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, raw-sockets

I setup a raw Packet socket using the following:

```
sockFd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL) );
```

Then I am trying to set the socket option `IP_HDRINCL` using:

```
int one = 1;
if (setsockopt (sockFd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &one, sizeof(one)) < 0)
    LogPrint(LOG_UNKNOWN,"Warning: Cannot set HDRINCL!\n");
```

But I am unable to set this option (I get an error with `errno` 92 and message "Protocol not available". If I change `PF_PACKET` to `PF_INET` then the options is set but I have to use `PF_PACKET`. So is there a way to set this option with the socket created above?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I'm not sure about this (at all), but does that option actually make sense for PF_PACKET sockets?

Comment: I don't have any idea either...this is someone else's code that I am working with. May I ask a question? I understand that the kernel doesn't add any ip headers when PF_PACKET is being used right? Does the kernel append the headers or de we have to manually do it? Stuff like source address and destination address etc.? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it  is my understanding that PF_PACKET sockets won't get headers added by the kernel  - not sure down to what "OSI layer" though. You'll have to make them yourself (and read the docs to determine exactly what headers you need to deal with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PF_PACKET` sockets don't have any option that I asked in the question to be set. That option is only available on `PF_INET` or `PF_INET6` sockets with type `SOCK_RAW`.

If one wants the IP headers to be added by the kernel, the one must use the `PF_INET` socket.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as following instead:

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
```

It implies that a socket is a raw socket with IP_HDRINCL set. If you use `getsockopt` to check the value of the socket, you will see IP_HDRINCL is already set.